# How exactly does PC/Mac generates random numbers for either 0 or 1?

Tags: random, cpu

This question is **NOT** about how to use any language to generate a random number between any interval. It is about generating either 0 or 1.

I understand that many random generator algorithm manipulate the very basic random(0 or 1) function and take seed from users and use an algorithm to generate various random numbers as needed.

The question is that how the CPU generate either 0 or 1? If I throw a coin, I can generate head or tailer. That's because I physically throw a coin and let the nature decide. But how does CPU do it? There must be **an action** that the CPU does (like throwing a coin) to get either 0 or 1 randomly, right?

Could anyone tell me about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This has several facets and thus several algorithms. Keep in mind that there are many different forms of randomness used for different purposes, but I understand your question in the way that you are interested in actual randomness used for cryptography.)*

The fundamental problem here is that computers are (mostly) deterministic machines. Given the same input in the same state they always yield the same result. However, there are a few ways of actually gathering entropy:

1. User input. Since users bring outside input into the system you can take that to derive some bits from that. Similar to how you could use radioactive decay or line noise.
2. Network activity. Again, an outside source of stuff.
3. Generally interrupts (which kinda include the first two).
4. As alluded to in the first item, noise from peripherals, such as audio input or a webcam can be used.
5. There is dedicated hardware that can generate a few hundred MiB of randomness per second. Usually they give you random numbers directly instead of their internal entropy, though.

How exactly you derive bits from that is up to you but you could use time between events, or actual content from the events, etc. – generally eliminating bias from entropy sources isn't easy or trivial and a lot of thought and algorithmic work goes into that (in the case of the aforementioned special hardware this is all done in hardware and the code using it doesn't need to care about it).

Once you have a pool of actually random bits you can just use them as random numbers (`/dev/random` on Linux does that). But this has downsides, since there is usually little actual entropy and possibly a higher demand for random numbers. So you can invent algorithms to “stretch” that initial randomness in a manner that makes it still impossible or at least very difficult to predict anything about following numbers (`/dev/urandom` on Linux or both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` on FreeBSD do that). [Fortuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29) and [Yarrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm) are so-called *cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generators* and designed with that in mind. You still have a very good guarantee about the quality of random numbers you generate, but have many more before your entropy pool runs out.

**In any case, the CPU itself cannot give you a random 0 or 1. There's a lot more involved and this usually includes the complete computer system or special hardware built for that purpose.**

---

There is also a second class of computational randomness: Plain vanilla pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs). What I said earlier about determinism – this is the embodiment of it. Given the same so-called *seed* a PRNG will yield the exact same sequence of numbers every time¹. While this sounds idiotic it has practical benefits.

Suppose you run a simulation involving lots of random numbers, maybe to simulate interaction between molecules or atoms that involve certain probabilities and unpredictable behaviour. In science you want results anyone can independently verify, given the same setup and procedure (or, with computing, the same algorithms). If you used actual randomness the only option you have would be to save every single random number used to make sure others can replicate the results independently.

But with a PRNG all you need to save is the seed and remember what algorithm you used. Others can then get the exact same sequence of pseudo-random numbers independently. Very nice property to have :-)

---

**Footnotes**

¹ This even includes the CSPRNGs mentioned above, but they are designed to be used in a special way that includes regular re-seeding with entropy to overcome that problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So you mean actually the CPU itself doesn't or is not able to really generate a naturally random 0 or 1. Instead, anyway, CPU needs some external factors to help to generate 0 or 1 randomly?

Comment: Indeed. I think I just added that sentence with my edit right now.

Answer (score 0):

A CPU can only generate a uniform random number, U(0,1), which happens to range from 0 to 1.  So mathematically, it would be defined as a random variable U in the range [0,1].  Examples of random draws of a U(0,1) random number in the range 0 to 1 would be 0.28100002, 0.34522, 0.7921, etc.  The probability of any value between 0 and 1 is equal, i.e., they are equiprobable.

You can generate binary random variates that are either 0 or 1 by setting a random draw of U(0,1) to a 0 if U(0,1)<=0.5 and 1 if U(0,1)>0.5, since in theory there will be an equal number of random draws of U(0,1) below 0.5 and above 0.5.